# PHP Basics: Can't deal with scope within classes

Tags: php

i got some trouble to understand scope in OOP. What i want is that $foo->test_item() prints "teststring"...Now it just fails with:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for testing::test_item()

Thanks a lot!

```
<?php

class testing {
    public $vari = "teststring";
    function test_item($vari){ //$this->vari doesn't work either
        print $vari;
    }
}

$foo = new testing();
$foo->test_item();

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test_item()` should be:

```
function test_item() {
    print $this->vari;
}
```

There is no need to pass `$vari` as a parameter.

Comment: @Georgo Thank you very much for answering...i know that this is not so intelligent. I want to test something with that...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you've declared a method which expects an argument, which is missing. You should do:

```
$foo->test_item("Something");
```

As for the `$this->`, that goes inside of the class methods.

```
function test_item(){
    print $this->vari;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

function parameters can not be as "$this->var",

change your class like

```
class testing {
    public $vari = "teststring";
    function test_item(){ //$this->vari doesn't work either
        print $this->vari;
    }
}

$foo = new testing();
$foo->test_item();
```

And read this  [Object-Oriented PHP for Beginners](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening there is that $foo->test_item() is expecting something passed as an argument, so for example

```
$foo->test_item("Hello");
```

Would be correct in this case. This would print `Hello`

**But**, you may be wondering why it doesn't print `teststring`. This is because by calling

```
print $vari;
```

you are only printing the variable that has been passed to $foo->test_item()

However, if instead you do

```
function test_item(){  //notice I've removed the argument passed to test_item here...
  print $this->vari;
}
```

You will instead be printing the value of the class `property` $vari. Use $this->... to call functions or variables within the scope of the class. If you try it without $this-> then PHP will look for that variable within the function's *local* scope